# Protected Class In C#

Tags: c#

This compiles well for me - However other people on a different thread are saying that protected classes cannot be declared in c# at top level

Is that the case?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    protected class CsvReader
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the code you've posted is not the whole story.  Just for the sake of sanity, try creating an empty, default Console application with only that code snippet in the class and compile.  It should fail.

Comment: @Richard: Good call--I wonder if the OP actually had `CsvReader` inside the `Program` class.

Comment: @Dan:  That's where my money is ... class Program { protected class CsvReader {} }

Comment: @serhio: It doesn't compile - at least, it doesn't for me under either VS2008 or VS2010. Have you actually tried to compile just that code?

Comment: @Jon: for me, does not compile in VS 2005:
`Error 1 Namespace elements cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't compile for me with either VS2008SP1 or VS2010 (using csc.exe from the command line in both cases).

Which compiler are you using?

From section 3.5.1 of the C# specification:

> - Types declared in compilation units
>     or namespaces can have `public` or
>     `internal` declared accessibility and
>     default to `internal` declared
>     accessibility.
> - Class members can
>     have any of the five kinds of declared
>     accessibility and default to `private`
>     declared accessibility. (Note that a
>     type declared as a member of a class
>     can have any of the five kinds of
>     declared accessibility, whereas a type
>     declared as a member of a namespace
>     can have only `public` or `internal`
>     declared accessibility.)

Comment: Ouch, I mixed it up with the constructor ... but it's on the class, my screw up.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw: Which version of VS? Maybe there was a bug around this area in VS2005, but it definitely doesn't compile in 2008 or 2010, and *shouldn't* compile.

Comment: The docs for VS2005 seem to suggest classes allow `protected` and `protected internal`, while structs are limited to the same modifiers that we're used to in VS2008+.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691127(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Jim: No, that page explicitly states: "Note that a type declared as a member of a class can have any of the five kinds of declared accessibility, whereas a type declared as a member of a namespace can have only public or internal declared accessibility."

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part.  I also VPN'd into my work computer and tried compiling this against Framework 1.1, which failed.

Comment: Ha, I like the mystery here. Question: Why does this compile? Accepted answer: It doesn't.

Comment: Mister Radshaw should be from India, there is a special every-time-compilable version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Consider: what would `protected` even *mean* on a top-level class. On a class member, it means that the member can be accessed by derived classes. But there's no such thing as a derived namespace, so what would `protected` even refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it compiles or not, but ask yourself this: what would this mean? It would **seem** to indicate that `CsvReader` could only be accessed from within the `ConsoleApplication1` namespace, **or any derived namespaces (?)**; but obviously this is nonsense. That's why it's not permitted in the spec. (At least that would be *my* explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

Classes cannot be declared as protected at top level becuase then no code would be able to access it (unless inherited but then you should use abstract classes). Why create code that cannot be accessed?